# Which Google api to use for getting user's first name, last name, picture, etc?

Tags: oauth, google-api

I have the oauth authorization with google working correctly and am getting data from the contacts api. Now, I want to programmatically get a gmail user's first name, last name and picture. Which google api can i use to get this data?

Comment: No one has any clue about this? I was surprised myself when I didn't find any simple answer on google's website...

Comment: Are you trying to get the name and picture for the contacts or for the user you authenticated?

Comment: For the user. Getting contacts info wont be difficult as there is an api for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer while looking around in the contacts API forum. When you get the result-feed, just do the following in Java-

```
String Name = resultFeed.getAuthors().get(0).getName();

String emailId = resultFeed.getId();
```

I am still looking for a way to get the user profile picture.

Comment: can you post some code sample for getting first name, last name, email from google. The url you are requesting. I am doing same in android app. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What has Java got to do with the Google APIs?

Answer (score 18):

The contacts API perhaps works, but you have to request permission from the user to access all contacts.  If I were a user, that would make me wary of granting the permission (because this essentially gives you permission to spam all my contacts...)

I found the response here to be useful, and only asks for "basic profile information":

[Get user info via Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130648/get-user-info-via-google-api)

I have successfully used this approach, and can confirm it returns the following Json object:

```
{
  "id": "..."
  "email": "...",
  "verified_email": true,
  "name": "....",
  "given_name": "...",
  "family_name": "...",
  "link": "...",
  "picture": "...",
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en"
}
```

Comment: +1 for this answer as it actually addresses the Google APIs that the question asked, as opposed to the current accepted answer which is just some random Java code.

Answer (score 6):

Use this code to get *firstName* and *lastName* of a google user:

```
final HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
        .setAudience(Arrays.asList(clientId))
        .setIssuer("https://accounts.google.com")
        .build();

GoogleIdToken idToken = null;
try {
    idToken = verifier.verify(googleAuthenticationPostResponse.getId_token());
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = null;
if (idToken != null) {
    payload = idToken.getPayload();
}
String firstName = payload.get("given_name").toString();
String lastName = payload.get("family_name").toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the google javascript API, you can use the new "auth2" API after authenticating to get the user's profile, containing:

- name
- email
- image URL

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetbasicprofile

Answer (score 1):

For the picture, you can use the Google contacts Data API too: see http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#retrieving_photo

Comment: but how do you retrieve the photo for the logged in user? I tried https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/myaccount@gmail.com?access_token=... but I get the error "Photo query failed - invalid contact ID".

Comment: In your URL, just URLencode the email address (write %40 instead of @) and it should work...

Comment: I've just discovered a new Google API that you can use: Portable Contacts API (http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/contacts/docs/poco/1.0/developers_guide.html) It's easier to retrieve the user photo: you authenticate with the scope https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/, you get user info with request https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/@me/@self and it contains the URL of the photo...

Comment: are you sure urlencoding the email should work? I just tried it and I keep getting the same error message. What I did to go around this was to use the Google Social API (https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/@me/@self) to get the user info. The only problem is that that url can only be called on the server-side because you need to set a custom OAuth authorization header.

Comment: This url https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/@me/@self isn't working now. Any idea on this ?

Comment: Yes, opensocial has been retired... Have you check https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=fr#retrieving_a_contacts_photo as an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get this information would be from the Google + API.  Specifically the

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get

When using the api use the following HTTP GET:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

This will return all of the above information requested from the user.

Comment: for anyone that comes here, the google+ API is shutting down more info here -> https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown

Answer (score -2):

Use this Code for Access Google Gmail Login Credential oAuth2 :

**Class Name : OAuthHelper**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.SortedSet;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.HttpRequestAdapter;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException;
import oauth.signpost.http.HttpParameters;
import oauth.signpost.signature.HmacSha1MessageSigner;
import oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.util.Log;

public class OAuthHelper {

private static final String TAG = "OAuthHelper";
private OAuthConsumer mConsumer;
private OAuthProvider mProvider;
private String mCallbackUrl;

public OAuthHelper(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String scope, String callbackUrl) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {


    mConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    mProvider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=" + URLEncoder.encode(scope, "utf-8"), "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken", "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?hd=default");
    mProvider.setOAuth10a(true);
    mCallbackUrl = (callbackUrl == null ? OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND : callbackUrl);
}

public String getRequestToken() throws OAuthMessageSignerException, OAuthNotAuthorizedException, OAuthExpectationFailedException, OAuthCommunicationException {
    String authUrl = mProvider.retrieveRequestToken(mConsumer, mCallbackUrl);
    System.out.println("Gautam AUTH URL : " + authUrl);
    return authUrl;
}

public String[] getAccessToken(String verifier) throws OAuthMessageSignerException, OAuthNotAuthorizedException, OAuthExpectationFailedException, OAuthCommunicationException {
    mProvider.retrieveAccessToken(mConsumer, verifier);
    return new String[] { mConsumer.getToken(), mConsumer.getTokenSecret() };
}

public String[] getToken() {
    return new String[] { mConsumer.getToken(), mConsumer.getTokenSecret() };
}

public void setToken(String token, String secret) {
    mConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
}

public String getUrlContent(String url) throws OAuthMessageSignerException, OAuthExpectationFailedException, OAuthCommunicationException, IOException {
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    // sign the request
    mConsumer.sign(request);
    // send the request
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    // get content
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String line = "";
    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(line + NL);
    in.close();
    System.out.println("gautam INFO : " + sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}

public String getUserProfile(String t0, String t1, String url) {

    try {
        OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(t0, t1);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        // sign the request
        consumer.sign(request);
        // send the request
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        //String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line );
        in.close();
        System.out.println("Gautam Profile  : " + sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in Geting profile Info : " + e);
        return "";
    } 

}

public String buildXOAuth(String email) {
    String url = String.format("https://mail.google.com/mail/b/%s/smtp/", email);
    HttpRequestAdapter request = new HttpRequestAdapter(new HttpGet(url));

    // Sign the request, the consumer will add any missing parameters
    try {
        mConsumer.sign(request);
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to sign xoauth http request " + e);
        return null;
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to sign xoauth http request " + e);
        return null;
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to sign xoauth http request " + e);
        return null;
    }

    HttpParameters params = mConsumer.getRequestParameters();
    // Since signpost doesn't put the signature into params,
    // we've got to create it again.
    OAuthMessageSigner signer = new HmacSha1MessageSigner();
    signer.setConsumerSecret(mConsumer.getConsumerSecret());
    signer.setTokenSecret(mConsumer.getTokenSecret());
    String signature;
    try {
        signature = signer.sign(request, params);
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "invalid oauth request or parameters " + e);
        return null;
    }
    params.put(OAuth.OAUTH_SIGNATURE, OAuth.percentEncode(signature));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("GET ");
    sb.append(url);
    sb.append(" ");
    int i = 0;
    for (Entry<String, SortedSet<String>> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue().first();
        int size = entry.getValue().size();
        if (size != 1)
            Log.d(TAG, "warning: " + key + " has " + size + " values");
        if (i++ != 0)
            sb.append(",");
        sb.append(key);
        sb.append("=\"");
        sb.append(value);
        sb.append("\"");
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "xoauth encoding " + sb);

    Base64 base64 = new Base64();
    try {
        byte[] buf = base64.encode(sb.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
        return new String(buf, "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "invalid string " + sb);
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

//===================================

**Create : WebViewActivity.class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

//WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    setContentView(webview);

    // Load the page
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getData() != null) {
        webview.loadUrl(intent.getDataString());
    }

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        // Show loading progress in activity's title bar.
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            setProgress(progress * 100);
        }
    });
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // When start to load page, show url in activity's title bar
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            setTitle(url);

            if (url.startsWith("my-activity")) {
                Intent result = new Intent();
                System.out.println("Gautam my-activity : " + url);
                result.putExtra("myurl", url);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
                finish();

            }


        }


        @Override
         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("Gautam Page Finish...");
           CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
           // Get the cookie from cookie jar.
           String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
           System.out.println("Gautam Cookie : " + cookie);
           if (cookie == null) {
             return;
           }
           // Cookie is a string like NAME=VALUE [; NAME=VALUE]
           String[] pairs = cookie.split(";");
           for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; ++i) {
             String[] parts = pairs[i].split("=", 2);
             // If token is found, return it to the calling activity.

             System.out.println("Gautam=> "+ parts[0] + "  =  " + parts[1]);
                if (parts.length == 2 && parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("oauth_token")) {
                    Intent result = new Intent();
                    System.out.println("Gautam AUTH : " + parts[1]);
                    result.putExtra("token", parts[1]);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
                    finish();
                }
           }
         }



    });


}
}
```

//=========================

**Call From : MainActivity.class**

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.http.HttpResponse;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button btnLogin;

OAuthHelper MyOuthHelper;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
protected void onResume() {


    /*System.out.println("On Resume call ");
    try {
        String[] token = getVerifier();
        if (token != null){
            String accessToken[] = MyOuthHelper.getAccessToken(token[1]);           
        }           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("gautam error on Resume : " + e);
    }*/



    super.onResume();
}

private String[] getVerifier(String url) {
    // extract the token if it exists
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    if (uri == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
    return new String[] { token, verifier };
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    try {
        MyOuthHelper = new OAuthHelper("YOUR CLIENT ID", "YOUR SECRET KEY", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "my-activity://localhost");         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("gautam errorin Class call :  " + e);
    }

    try {
        String uri = MyOuthHelper.getRequestToken();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


 /*         startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
        Uri.parse(uri)));*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Gautm Error in getRequestTokan : " + e);

    }
}



@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   switch (requestCode) {
     case 0:
       if (resultCode != RESULT_OK || data == null) {
         return;
       }
       // Get the token.
       String url = data.getStringExtra("myurl");
       try {
            String[] token = getVerifier(url);
            if (token != null){
                String accessToken[] = MyOuthHelper.getAccessToken(token[1]);
                System.out.println("Gautam Final [0] : " + accessToken[0]  + "   , [1]  : " + accessToken[1]);

                //https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json

 //                 String myProfile = MyOuthHelper.getUserProfile(accessToken[0], accessToken[1], "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json");
                String myProfile = MyOuthHelper.getUrlContent("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json");

            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("gautam error on Resume : " + e);
        }
       return;
   }
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }





 }
```

//=================================

And Finally Your Profile Information coming,  Just Look in your Logcat message print.

***Note :  Not Forgot to put Internet Permission in Manifest File***

***And Your App Register in Google Console for Client ID and Secret Key***
For App Registration Please Looking this Step : [App Registration Step](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/07/google-oauth-overview/)