# Get user info via Google API

Tags: oauth, google-api, userinfo

Is it possible to get information from user's profile via Google API? If it is possible, which API should I use?

I'm interesting in such information:

- Url to the user profile (e.g. https://profiles.google.com/115063121183536852887);
- Gender (sex);
- Profile photo.

Also it would be cool to get other information from user's profile.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Add this to the scope - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

And after authorization is done, get the information from - https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json

It has loads of stuff -  including name, public profile url, gender, photo etc.

Comment: I used the above Urls but unable to get user's profile. Getting '{' only. Plz can u post some code or links. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm, just authorize the request with OAuth 2. That URL returns data for the currently signed-in user. It'll give you an error if you make the request without sending the OAuth header though.

Comment: The url you provided works perfectly, i.e https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo . But can you tell where from did you get this url. I tried searching for it but didn't find it anywhere. Does Google document these urls at some place?

Comment: Where can I see specification of data returned for specific scope ?

Comment: Scope "userinfo.profile" seems to be deprecated, instead you should use "profile" and "email". https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#authorization-scopes

Comment: i can't get gender info (i have kept gender info public) using this scope. i have tried oauth playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground for this. i want to do this using REST API on server side. can you help me on this?

Comment: can anyone answer my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632883/enable-google-api-for-googleapis-com-auth-userinfo

Comment: You can just query this url, using the access token you get after user has authorized you to access this scope. Example: `curl -X GET "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json" -H"Authorization: Bearer accessTokenHere"`

Comment: For the future reference, refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtaininguserprofileinformation) page on "Google Identity Platform". The url works with `https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo` and the response structure is under "5. Obtain user information from the ID token" section.

Comment: As of July 2021, please reference this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67913727/8442938 for the most up-to-date info.

Answer (score 104):

scope - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

```
return youraccess_token = access_token
```

get https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=youraccess_token

you will get json:

```
{
 "id": "xx",
 "name": "xx",
 "given_name": "xx",
 "family_name": "xx",
 "link": "xx",
 "picture": "xx",
 "gender": "xx",
 "locale": "xx"
}
```

To Tahir Yasin:

This is a php example.
You can use json_decode function to get userInfo array.

```
$q = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=xxx';
$json = file_get_contents($q);
$userInfoArray = json_decode($json,true);
$googleEmail = $userInfoArray['email'];
$googleFirstName = $userInfoArray['given_name'];
$googleLastName = $userInfoArray['family_name'];
```

Comment: how to can I use their response?

Comment: How can i get the email address along with the other information that you have mentioned ?

Comment: Please, update the code to have correct format to access `$userInfoArray` properties. It should be like `$userInfoArray['email']` to get the email address from the `$userInfoArray`. NOTE THE SINGLE QUOTATION TO ACCESS RPOPERTIES.

Comment: @Shantha Kumara you could have edited it yourself, but don't worry as I have done it now. For all we know they could have omitted the code `define(email, 'email')` ;)

Comment: i want to get phone number and age/birthday

Comment: I was stuck on this since a few hours and surprisingly your answer was the only one which showed an example of how to achieve this. Thanks a ton !

Comment: I had a difficult time trying to find out the correct api url. So may I ask you how would you find a correct API of Google APIs? For example to get the email of authenticated user (OAuth2) @eason

Answer (score 30):

This is poorly document / there have been changes. I would reference this https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground for up to date endpoints.

As of `2021` the correct endpoint for `userinfo` is

`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo`

So once you get the `access_token` you can do

```
curl -X GET "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo" \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>"
```

**Important:** To get all the information you need `scope` of `openid email profile`.

```
{
 'sub': '<unique_id>',
 'name': '<full>',
 'given_name': '<first>',
 'family_name': '<last>',
 'picture': '<pic>',
 'email': '<email>',
 'email_verified': True,
 'locale': 'en'
}
```

Comment: I was struggling to find the email field specifically, and this answer solved my problem! I can verify this works. Thank you!

Comment: super helpful and correct 2021 answer--in my case the 'sub' field was `id` and 'email_verified' was `verified_email`, using a GET with Bearer token of `v2` and `v1` urls https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo however `v3` url shows the `sub` and `email_verified` fields, try with GET+Bearer for https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo

Comment: Ah interesting wasn't paying too much attention to the version but sounds like there is some differences in response between them.

Comment: @GlenThompson We need age and gender as well, how we get it from gmail?

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I didn't get the correct scope for a while to also include the email and tried out a lot of different options.
For me it works fine with just the scope: profile email

Comment: You can check correct URLs on the standard OpenID url path: https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Answer (score 28):

This scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile has been deprecated now. Please look at https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable.

New scope you will be using to get profile info is: profile or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

and the endpoint is - https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userId} - userId can be just 'me' for currently logged in user.

Comment: This one is important peace of information towards having integration future proof. more information about deprecated scopes https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth

Comment: and yet ... `If you are directly requesting the “plus.me” scope, any other Google+ OAuth scopes, or making any Google+ API calls, please ensure that you remove these requests from your project before March 7, 2019.` -- Google

Answer (score 26):

I'm using `PHP` and solved this by using version 1.1.4 of [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Assuming the following code is used to redirect a user to the Google authentication page:

```
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAuthConfigFile('/path/to/config/file/here');
 $client->setRedirectUri('https://redirect/url/here');
 $client->setAccessType('offline'); //optional
 $client->setScopes(['profile']); //or email
 $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
 header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
 exit();
```

Assuming a valid authentication code is returned to the `redirect_url`, the following will generate a token from the authentication code as well as provide basic profile information:

```
 //assuming a successful authentication code is return
 $authentication_code = 'code-returned-by-google';
 $client = new Google_Client();
 //.... configure $client object code goes here
 $client->authenticate($authentication_code);
 $token_data = $client->getAccessToken();

 //get user email address
 $google_oauth =new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
 $google_account_email = $google_oauth->userinfo->get()->email;
 //$google_oauth->userinfo->get()->familyName;
 //$google_oauth->userinfo->get()->givenName;
 //$google_oauth->userinfo->get()->name;
 //$google_oauth->userinfo->get()->gender;
 //$google_oauth->userinfo->get()->picture; //profile picture
```

However, location is not returned. [New YouTube accounts don't have YouTube specific usernames](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1637615?hl=en-GB)

Comment: how to get Location?

Comment: i can't get gender info (i have kept gender info public) using this scope. i have tried oauth playground developers.google.com/oauthplayground for this. i want to do this using REST API on server side. can you help me on this?

Comment: Can't get gender neither. And on some account, nothing except email are returned. Ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

I am using Google API for .Net, but no doubt you can find the same way to obtain this information using other version of API.
As **user872858** mentioned, scope *userinfo.profile* has been deprecated ([google article](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes)) .

To obtain user profile info I use following code (re-written part from [google's example](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp)):

```
IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                                  new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                                      {
                                            ClientSecrets = Secrets,
                                            Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin,"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"  }
                                       });    
TokenResponse _token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("", code, "postmessage", 
                              CancellationToken.None).Result;

                    // Create an authorization state from the returned token.
                    context.Session["authState"] = _token;

                    // Get tokeninfo for the access token if you want to verify.
                    Oauth2Service service = new Oauth2Service(
                     new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer());
                    Oauth2Service.TokeninfoRequest request = service.Tokeninfo();
                    request.AccessToken = _token.AccessToken;
                    Tokeninfo info = request.Execute();
                    if (info.VerifiedEmail.HasValue && info.VerifiedEmail.Value)
                    {
                        flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                                    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                                         {
                                             ClientSecrets = Secrets,
                                             Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin }
                                          });

                        UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(flow, 
                                                              "me", _token);
                        _token = credential.Token;
                        _ps = new PlusService(
                              new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
                               {
                                   ApplicationName = "Your app name",
                                   HttpClientInitializer = credential
                               });
                        Person userProfile = _ps.People.Get("me").Execute();
                    }
```

Than, you can access almost anything using userProfile.

UPDATE: To get this code working you have to use appropriate scopes on google sign in button. For example my button:

```
     <button class="g-signin"
             data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"
             data-clientid="646361778467-nb2uipj05c4adlk0vo66k96bv8inqles.apps.googleusercontent.com"
             data-accesstype="offline"
             data-redirecturi="postmessage"
             data-theme="dark"
             data-callback="onSignInCallback"
             data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
             data-width="iconOnly">
     </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 steps that needs to be run.

1. Register your app's client id from Google API console
2. Ask your end user to give consent using this api https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#sendauthrequest
3. Use google's oauth2 api as described at https://any-api.com/googleapis_com/oauth2/docs/userinfo/oauth2_userinfo_v2_me_get using the token obtained in step 2. (Though still I could not find how to fill "fields" parameter properly).

It is very interesting that this simplest usage is not clearly described anywhere. And *i believe* there is a danger, you should pay attention to the `verified_email`parameter coming in the response. Because *if I am not wrong* it may yield fake emails to register your application. (This is just my interpretation, has a fair chance that I may be wrong!)

I find facebook's OAuth mechanics much much clearly described.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to fetch the Google user id, name and picture for a visitor of your web app - here is my pure PHP service side solution for the year 2020 with no external libraries used -

If you read the [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) guide by Google (and beware, Google likes to change links to its own documentation), then you have to perform only 2 steps:

1. Present the visitor a web page asking for the consent to share her name with your web app
2. Then take the "code" passed by the above web page to your web app and fetch a token (actually 2) from Google.

One of the returned tokens is called "id_token" and contains the user id, name and photo of the visitor.

Here is the PHP code of [a web game](https://slova.de/words/google/) by me. Initially I was using Javascript SDK, but then I have noticed that fake user data could be passed to my web game, when using client side SDK only (especially the user id, which is important for my game), so I have switched to using PHP on the server side:

```
<?php

const APP_ID       = '1234567890-abcdefghijklmnop.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const APP_SECRET   = 'abcdefghijklmnopq';

const REDIRECT_URI = 'https://the/url/of/this/PHP/script/';
const LOCATION     = 'Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?';
const TOKEN_URL    = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';
const ERROR        = 'error';
const CODE         = 'code';
const STATE        = 'state';
const ID_TOKEN     = 'id_token';

# use a "random" string based on the current date as protection against CSRF
$CSRF_PROTECTION   = md5(date('m.d.y'));

if (isset($_REQUEST[ERROR]) && $_REQUEST[ERROR]) {
    exit($_REQUEST[ERROR]);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST[CODE]) && $_REQUEST[CODE] && $CSRF_PROTECTION == $_REQUEST[STATE]) {
    $tokenRequest = [
        'code'          => $_REQUEST[CODE],
        'client_id'     => APP_ID,
        'client_secret' => APP_SECRET,
        'redirect_uri'  => REDIRECT_URI,
        'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
    ];

    $postContext = stream_context_create([
        'http' => [
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($tokenRequest)
        ]
    ]);

    # Step #2: send POST request to token URL and decode the returned JWT id_token
    $tokenResult = json_decode(file_get_contents(TOKEN_URL, false, $postContext), true);
    error_log(print_r($tokenResult, true));
    $id_token    = $tokenResult[ID_TOKEN];
    # Beware - the following code does not verify the JWT signature! 
    $userResult  = json_decode(base64_decode(str_replace('_', '/', str_replace('-', '+', explode('.', $id_token)[1]))), true);

    $user_id     = $userResult['sub'];
    $given_name  = $userResult['given_name'];
    $family_name = $userResult['family_name'];
    $photo       = $userResult['picture'];

    if ($user_id != NULL && $given_name != NULL) {
        # print your web app or game here, based on $user_id etc.
        exit();
    }
}

$userConsent = [
    'client_id'     => APP_ID,
    'redirect_uri'  => REDIRECT_URI,
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope'         => 'profile',
    'state'         => $CSRF_PROTECTION,
];

# Step #1: redirect user to a the Google page asking for user consent
header(LOCATION . http_build_query($userConsent));

?>
```

You could use a PHP library to add additional security by verifying the JWT signature. For my purposes it was unnecessary, because I trust that Google will not betray my little web game by sending fake visitor data.

Also, if you want to get more personal data of the visitor, then you need a third step:

```
const USER_INFO    = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=';
const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'access_token'; 

# Step #3: send GET request to user info URL
$access_token = $tokenResult[ACCESS_TOKEN];
$userResult = json_decode(file_get_contents(USER_INFO . $access_token), true);
```

Or you could get more permissions on behalf of the user - see the long list at the [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) doc.

Finally, the APP_ID and APP_SECRET constants used in my code - you get it from the [Google API console](https://console.developers.google.com/):

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

if you use Oath2 then client will give id_token

then you can validate it on server with this url

`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=your_id_token`

will solve problem like lucky charm

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a client-side web environment, the new auth2 javascript API contains a much-needed `getBasicProfile()` function, which returns the user's name, email, and image URL.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetbasicprofile

Comment: But what is the actual API URL? I looked at the documentation, I can't find the actual API URL. Google seem to be pushing us to their SDK, but not everyone wants to use the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get the **id** and **accessToken** using the new **Google Identity Services API**

**JS Code**

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>
$(document).on("click", ".login-google", function(e) {
    const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: 'your_client_id',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        callback: (tokenResponse) => {
            if (tokenResponse && tokenResponse.access_token) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=" + tokenResponse.access_token,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        let externalModel = {
                            authProvider: 'Google',
                            providerKey: data.id,
                            providerAccessCode: tokenResponse.access_token
                        };
                        abp.ui.setBusy();
                        abp.ajax({
                            url: window.location.origin + '/api/SocialLogin',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            data: JSON.stringify(externalModel),
                            success: function(data) {
                                if (data.accessToken) {
                                    location.href = window.location.origin;
                                }
                                abp.ui.clearBusy();
                            },
                            error: function(e) {
                                console.log("error on login:", e)
                            }
                        }).always(function() {
                            abp.ui.clearBusy();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        },
    });
    client.requestAccessToken();
});
```

**Explanation**

1. Add gsi/client script
2. On the button click Create an object of TokenClient
3. Pass three parameters (client_id, scope, and callback which will get the token response)
4. Call `client.requestAccessToken();` method to popup Google sign-in screen
5. After a successful google signin, response will be handled by the callback handler that you mention in the TokenClient parameters
6. Create a get request to [Get Profile](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=your_access_token) URL and pass accessToken in the query string parameter.
7. On its success method you will see the profile informations
8. The rest of the tasks are managed by my backend which is ASPNet Boilerplate using .Net Core 2.2