# Getting user profile with google oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, user-profile

I'm trying to get user profile information upon logging in with google-oauth2. User successfully logs in and i can get the access_token and can refresh the token when needed.
Though i could not manage to get any information about the user despite reading the docs and trying for hours.

From "Retrieving profiles" section of [developers guide](http://code.google.com/intl/tr/googleapps/domain/profiles/developers_guide.html) :

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domainName/full
```

should be enough. i've tried with "gmail.com", "google.com", "gmail", "google", "orkut", "orkut.com" , myregisteredappsdomainname (and .com) as domainName. i've also tried it with

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domainName/full?access_token=access_token_for_user
```

all i managed to get was 401 error, where it says "That’s an error.". Regarding 401 error, I've refreshed the token and tried again with new token, but kept getting 401s.

How can i get profile information and image address for user upon logging in?

Answer (score 2):

The scope you're looking for is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
```

This has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130648/get-user-info-via-google-api)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar errors requesting profiles even after correctly defining the scope and getting access tokens etc.. The trick for me was to include the API version on my requests. See here for more info http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/profiles/developers_guide.html#Versioning

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my situation, i was completely lost in vast amount of google's api documents regarding oauth, oauth2, opensocial etc. I managed to dug my way out and found out that all i needed was some small modification in codes and providing the correct scopes. For google profiles with oauth2, i needed  to add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile scope

Answer (score 0):

Maybe little late yet could this be helpful to someone. Below is the working code I wrote to get gplus user profile

In HTML below markup will display goolge signIn button

```
<span id="signinButton">
    <span
      class="g-signin"
      data-callback="signinCallback"
      data-clientid="YOUR GPLUS CLIENT ID"
      data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
      data-scope="email">
    </span>
</span>
```

Below is the java script

```
 var access_token;
/**
 * Called when the Google+ client library reports authorization status.
 */
function signinCallback(authResult) {
    access_token = authResult.access_token;

    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
        gapi.client.plus.people.get({ userId: 'me' }).execute(printProfile);
    });
}

/**
 * Response callback for when the API client receives a response.
 *
 * @param resp The API response object with the user email and profile information.
 */
function printProfile(resp) {
    if (resp.code != 403) {
     console.log('name:' + access_token.givenname);
     console.log('last name:' + access_token.lastname);
     console.log('email:' + access_token.emails[0]);
     console.log('gender:' + access_token.gender);
     console.log('profile image url:' + access_token.image.url);
    }
}
```

Please make sure that you load google api javascript asynchronously within the body tag as below

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function () {
                    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                })();
</script>
```

To handle logout refer to the answer I provide in below link, you will need to store access_token in backend so that during logout call this to be used, in my case I have stored in session and getting through ajax call 
[gapi.auth.signOut(); not working I'm lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086301/gapi-auth-signout-not-working-im-lost/24896706#24896706)

Answer (score -1):

Hey why don't you look at the code given at:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/OAuth4Client.aspx

It definitely helps you. The project is actually an oauth playground to send correct oauth header to correct endpoints.

Comment: The article is not about Google API