# Getting the gender,birthday,photo from google UserInfo

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, userinfo

I am trying to get the birthday,gender and photo information.
I added two url into scope "userinfo.email" and "userinfo.profile" into scope.

when my program redirects to below link,

"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=329032112127.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://userdetails1.appspot.com/UserServlet1&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"

If user is not login in. It shows the login window. I do not want to do that.
I want that , it gets automatically login or else just bypass the login page and give back me user information.

Now when i login then it is giving back me response. I do not want like that.

Is there any other way...? Please replay..?

Comment: It only prompts for a login if the user is not already logged in. 
"...bypass the login page and give back me user information". If you bypass the login page, how can you know who the user is?

Comment: I am thinking to pass user id or email and get back the response. Not sure will it work or no..?

Comment: Check if this is useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130648/get-user-info-via-google-api

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I understand, but have a look at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login - it seems like prompt=none will either silently succeed (if already approved) or silently fail.  Is that what you want?  But you can’t get the userinfo without a login/approval having happened.

Comment: okie. Means There is no other way. User should need to login then we will get the response.  Thanks!