# Strong naming Google.Apis

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm currently in the process of developing a calendar synchronization with Google Calendar.

Since the NuGet variants of the Google.Apis package are not strong named, I've tried to sign them myself (using ILASM and ILDASM). Unfortunately, this results in the following build error:

`The type 'Google.Apis.Authentication.IAuthenticator' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.2.4737.25313, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

Now I've tried downloading the source code (from: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/) and compiling them myself. This does work, however the Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 dll is missing.

Now I've found it here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Services/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.cs?repo=samples&r=4ce33c684dd8e6f11b441f685149856c6735e51b

But I don't know how I can approach this whole thing. Aren't there any ready-to-use DLLs for Google Calendar integration, which are strongly named?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are going to have to compile theme yourself.

The source for Google Calendar dll can be found at: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/calendar/v3/csharp

No they haven't released a strong name version It has been requested again and again for the last sevral years [Strong naming in binaries](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=238&can=1&q=strong&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary) Feel free to add your name to it if enough of us request it maybe just maybe they might do it.

I hope this helps.

UPDATE (July 23rd):
Google APIs client library for .NET version 1.9.2 was just released and it includes signed dlls.
Take a look at the announcement:
http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/2015/07/announcing-release-of-192.html

Comment: How did you find the source code to the calendar library? I'm now looking for the library that gives me access to the UserInfo, but have been unable to find them... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310307/access-user-info-using-google-apis-for-net

Comment: I think user info is Google+ api try changing it while I ping someone who will know the answer

Comment: Sounds promising, navigating to the following page lead me to the source code: https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/download/library/plus/v1/csharp