# Google.Apis SDK: Google+ sharing in windows phone

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

I have integrated *Google.Apis* SDK in my windows phone 8.1 store app. I have not found any API to share interactive posts on google+.

**Is that API is available in *`Google.APis`* SDK? If yes, Which one?**

For iOS [GPPNativeShareBuilder](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/#add_native_sharing) is used for sharing.

For Android PlusShare.Builder](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/interactive-post) is used

How to do this in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime app?.

Thanks

Comment: Which g+ API to add?

Answer (score 1):

Although a native solution does not exist for Windows, you can still build share links by sending a user to:

```
http://plus.google.com/share?url=<URL>
```

For example, [here's a share to this post](https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339060/google-apis-sdk-google-sharing-in-windows-phone).