# Get profile picture from Gmail Account

Tags: ios7, ios6

I am currently working with an application which has to set a profile image.Can I get profile picture from Gmail account in IOS 7?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138474/2833567).you need to follow these steps.It has loads of stuff - including name, public profile url, gender, photo etc.

Answer (score 0):

for Profile picture in Gmail account........
after successful login in gmail use this code

```
GTLPlusPerson *gpUser =  [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] googlePlusUser];
if([[gpUser image] url])
        {
           UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[gpUser image] url]]]];
        }
```