# .NET Google API V3 - How to access user email address

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-calendar-api

I know about the existence of "email" scope, but in .net google api v3 terms does anybody know the answer to this supposedly simple yet tricky problem?

I finally set everything up, am able to access and manipulate user calendars however I please, but for feedback purposes it would be ideal to display the selected email to the user.

I got around it by doing the following, but there has to be a proper way of doing this:

```
IList<CalendarListEntry> ListOfCalendars = service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items;
```

Based on the assumption that the .Summary of the last entry of the above list will always be the user's default calendar name, I can obtain the email address, but come on this is a crime...

Does anyone have an idea or happens to be in the same boat as me with this?

Thanks for the feedback in advance!

Comment: This question would probably help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130648/get-user-info-via-google-api

Comment: Hmm, interesting, should do, I'll do some tests later on today