# How to get user info via Google API using js OR curl

Tags: javascript, google-api-client, google-oauth, google-client-login

I have checked [answer how to get user info via Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130648/get-user-info-via-google-api), but it does not help to resolve the issue because of API was changed and some links are incorrect.

Google uses `oauth2`, so to load any user info via js we need follow next steps:

- invite user to authorize in `google service` to get his personal oauth token;
- get users token from `google service` answer;
- make request to load users info (request should be subscribed his personal token).

**Am I correct with this steps?**

[In google guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) they wrote to authorize user should be used next API  **https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth**. If I login myself I can see request sends to **https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password**

**Can I have a `curl` example how to get users oauth token (to use it in next requests to load users data)?**

Comment: google already provides really good information for that. and they have a good support, ask them...

Comment: in [developer descriptions](https://developers.google.com) they wrote to ask questions on stackoverflow (see at page bottom please).