# Spring-boot app works locally but not when deployed to appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a application made with spring-boot that uses OAuth2 from spring-security with the annotation `@EnableOAuth2Sso`. When I run the app locally it works perfectly but when I deploy to google app-engine. I get a Server Error 500.

I think it has something to do with how my credentials are set because the error occurs at `SocialTokenServicesConfiguration`. When I remove the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` the app works when deployed. It's weird how the app can work with the OAuth2 locally but not when deployed.

Whole stack trace:
Application startup failed

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration$SocialTokenServicesConfiguration.socialTokenServices
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:650) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:612) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:582) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:776) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112-google-v7]

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.collect(OnBeanCondition.java:329) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:282) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:76) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
... 37 common frames omitted

 ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17db13e5: startup date [Sun Sep 17 19:26:44 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy


Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close


java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17db13e5: startup date [Sun Sep 17 19:26:44 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:999) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:650) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:612) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:582) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:776) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112-google-v7


Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17db13e5: startup date [Sun Sep 17 19:26:44 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [runtime-impl-third-party.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:650) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:612) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:582) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:776) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263) [runtime-impl.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112-google-v7


Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration$SocialTokenServicesConfiguration.socialTokenServices
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:650)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:612)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:582)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:776)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.collect(OnBeanCondition.java:329)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:282)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:76)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
... 37 more


com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyLogger warn: Failed startup of context c.g.a.r.j.AppEngineWebAppContext@758f7d64{/,file:///base/data/home/apps/e~computetest-175618/20170917t212523.404176911738420356/,UNAVAILABLE}{/base/data/home/apps/e~computetest-175618/20170917t212523.404176911738420356}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration$SocialTokenServicesConfiguration.socialTokenServices
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:650)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:612)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:582)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:776)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration$SocialTokenServicesConfiguration.socialTokenServices
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
... 17 more


Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration$SocialTokenServicesConfiguration.socialTokenServices
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:650)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:612)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:582)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:776)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please post entire stacktrace.

Comment: Yes I added the stack trace now. @KrishnaKuntala

Comment: From the initial looks, it seems that the problem is due to spring version. Try changing spring version to 1.5.4.

Comment: Just tried changing to 1.5.4.RELEASE. Still same error. If I remove `@EnableOAuth2Sso` it works perfectly. @KrishnaKuntala