# How to fetch user's age and location while doing google signin

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-signin

I am integrating google signin in my app.I need to store email,name,agerange,location.So while doing signin, i have set the scope to profile,email and profile.auth.agerange.read.

```
gapi.signin2.render('g-signin2', {
    'scope': 'email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.agerange.read',
    'width': 240,
    'height': 50,
    'longtitle': true,
    'theme': 'dark',
    'onsuccess': onSuccess,
    'onfailure': onFailure
  });
```

But still when i am verifying the generated id_token using GoogleIdTokenVerifier i can't see age or location field in the payload.

Can anyone suggest how to get those details.

Comment: Hi Manish, have you ever found solution for this. Do we need to call API separately for getting age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely location and age group wouldn't be provided with a basic payload.
And you would be needed to call an additional API(s):

- [GET v1/people/me?personFields=ageRanges](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/people/v1/people.people.get?resourceName=people%252Fme&personFields=ageRanges&_h=22&) with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile scope;
- [GET v1/people/me?personFields=birthdays](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/people/v1/people.people.get?resourceName=people%252Fme&personFields=birthdays&_h=2&) with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read scope.

Also, take a look into [get-user-info-via-google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130648/get-user-info-via-google-api) topic.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#agerangetype

You can also get dob from api and calculate the age of the user.
location string can also get from the rest api response from google.