# How can I create my custom login with google without socialite?

Tags: laravel, google-authentication

I want to log in with google but i don't want use socialite.Is there link that I can reder and get my user info?

Comment: didn't explored about whole process of custom google sign-in, but just for getting the user info may [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67913727/7574023) can help you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a beautiful way of doing this, it is kinda an easy task but all u need is to go through this documentation of google

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview

use their Api to achieve the login feature, generate html code which will be used to popup the login dialog box, div has an attribute to mention redirect uri where ur google data will come

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR CLIENT ID"
     data-context="signup"
     data-ux_mode="popup"
     data-login_uri="http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback"
     data-auto_select="true"
     data-itp_support="true">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
```

then before accessing data u should have install the package to verify data while fetching data for the security purpose u should have install this pkg

```
composer require google/apiclient     

// Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
  $userid = $payload['sub']; 
} else {
  // Invalid ID token
}
```

this helps to verify the request and data, this method returns payload which we can use according to our need