# Attempting to retrieve user's email, name & gender after a "Sign in with Google" (C#) from the server

Tags: oauth, google-api, userinfo

I've added the "Sign in with Google" button to my web app. This part is working successfully, when clicked, I'm shown the Google sign in/authorization screen.

Next I taking the return code back from google and am attempting to follow the code sample from a prior answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24510353

```cs
IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
ClientSecrets = Secrets,
Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin,
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"  }});    

TokenResponse _token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("", code, "postmessage", CancellationToken.None).Result;

// Create an authorization state from the returned token.
context.Session["authState"] = _token;

// Get tokeninfo for the access token if you want to verify.
Oauth2Service service = new Oauth2Service(
new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer());

Oauth2Service.TokeninfoRequest request = service.Tokeninfo();
request.AccessToken = _token.AccessToken;
Tokeninfo info = request.Execute();

if (info.VerifiedEmail.HasValue && info.VerifiedEmail.Value)
{
flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer                                         {
  ClientSecrets = Secrets,
  Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin }
});

UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(flow,"me", _token);_token = credential.Token;
_ps = new PlusService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
ApplicationName = "Your app name",
HttpClientInitializer = credential
});

Person userProfile = _ps.People.Get("me").Execute();
}
```

When the ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync is called, I get an exception "Error:'invalid_grant', Description:'Malformed auth code.', Uri:''"

Truthfully, the code there seems awfully convoluted, surely there's an easier way?

The sample code uses 'postmessage' in the URL parameter, on the off chance it really requires a valid URL, I substituted a valid 'Authorized redirect URI's' from my projects credentials panel, but with the same results.

I've looked at endless posts on both "invalid_grant" & how to retrieve credentials.  Vast majority of both are 8+ years old and deal with deprecated code/functions/apis...

Some guidance here would be wonderful!

---

Update to clarify I'm attempting this from the server side.  I see many responses indicating using 'GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker' as part of the solution, but this is only from front end code and (per the docs) shouldn't be run on the back end.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  You should either go though the userinfo endpoint or the people api.