# Google API OAuth User info

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I am working with google OAuth API to get user info using [this url](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json)

With the scopes

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
>    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

I got the following response

```
 { "id": "123456788", "name": "Joe Shmoe", 
   "given_name": "Joe", "family_name": "Shmoe", 
   "link": "https://plus.google.com/1234567788", 
   "picture": "https://IMAGE_URL/photo.jpg", 
   "gender": "male", "birthday": "0000-03-10", "locale": "en-GB"}
```

I am looking for email but it is not available in response.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2108537/1056359

Answer (score 0):

It's because google proifle API answer with extended information only to those circles which you allow to see it in you personal info visibility settings.

For instance, if you allow to your friends circle to see your mobile and private email -- they can see it (but only peoples and apps added into those circle).

By default all apps are guests (public).