# Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson deprecated in Play services 8.4. How to get user's first name, last name and gender using GoogleSignInApi?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, google-plus-signin

With Play services 8.4, the method [getCurrentPerson](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People.html#getCurrentPerson(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) is deprecated and I was using the PeopleApi to get user's first name, last name and gender.

Can anyone tell me how to get the signed in user's info using another method?

Comment: Have you tried using [GoogleSignInResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInResult)?

Comment: The only object containing data about the user in GoogleSignInResult is GoogleSignInAccount which doesn't contain the data I need.

Comment: I found this old [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108537/which-google-api-to-use-for-getting-users-first-name-last-name-picture-etc). I hope this will help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Google Sign-In API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people) can already provide you with first / last / display name, email and profile picture url. If you need other profile information like gender, use it in conjunction with new [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/)

```
// Add dependencies
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev4-1.22.0'
```

Then write sign-in code,

```
// Make sure your GoogleSignInOptions request profile & email
GoogleSignInOptions gso =
        new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
// Follow official doc to sign-in.
// https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in
```

When handling sign-in result:

```
GoogleSignInResult result =
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
if (result.isSuccess()) {
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
    String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
    String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
    String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
    String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
    String personId = acct.getId();
    Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
}
```

Use People Api to retrieve detailed person info.

```
/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

// On worker thread
GoogleAccountCredential credential =
         GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this, Scopes.PROFILE);
credential.setSelectedAccount(new Account(personEmail, "com.google"));
People service = new People.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME /* whatever you like */) 
                .build();
// All the person details
Person meProfile = service.people().get("people/me").execute();
// e.g. Gender
List<Gender> genders = meProfile.getGenders();
String gender = null;
if (genders != null && genders.size() > 0) {
    gender = genders.get(0).getValue();
}
```

Take a look at [JavaDoc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/people/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/people/v1/model/package-summary.html) to see what other profile information you can get.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** Check Isabella's answer. This answer uses deprecated stuff.

I found the solution myself so I'm posting it here if anyone else faces the same problem.

Although I was looking for a solution for using GoogleSignInApi to get user's info, I couldn't find that and I think we need to use the Plus Api to get info like gender.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
```

HandleSignInResult

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess())
        {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+acct.getDisplayName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             Plus.PeopleApi.load(mGoogleApiClient, acct.getId()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                    Person person = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().get(0);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Person loaded");
                    Log.d(TAG,"GivenName "+person.getName().getGivenName());
                    Log.d(TAG,"FamilyName "+person.getName().getFamilyName());
                    Log.d(TAG,("DisplayName "+person.getDisplayName()));
                    Log.d(TAG,"Gender "+person.getGender());
                    Log.d(TAG,"Url "+person.getUrl());
                    Log.d(TAG,"CurrentLocation "+person.getCurrentLocation());
                    Log.d(TAG,"AboutMe "+person.getAboutMe());
                    Log.d(TAG,"Birthday "+person.getBirthday());
                    Log.d(TAG,"Image "+person.getImage());
                }
            });

            //mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
            //updateUI(true);
        } else {
            //updateUI(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Plus.PeopleApi has been deprecated. See deprecation notes below:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/api-deprecation. If you want to get profile information other than first / last / display name, email and profile picture url (which is already provided by the GoogleSignInAccount), use new People REST API. See code sample in my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @IsabellaChen Thanks for the link, The profile picture (url) returned in GoogleSignInAccount is very small. Is there a way to get a bigger picture? I do not want to show a blurred picture of the user on my UI.

Comment: Unfortunately, no recommended approach at this moment. 96*96 photo is served right now. Most apps simply display a thumbnail and this size is enough for them. If you look at a profile photo url, you will see it ends with "s96-c/photo.jpg", which at this moment means 96*96. But no guarantee the schema won't change in the future. So I don't recommend changing the url yourself.

Comment: @IsabellaChen I'm actually changing s96-c to sXXX-c to get the size I want. There should be a better/documented way to get a bigger image. 96x96 is too small to be shown on mobile screens which are getting bigger and denser every year.

Comment: Like I said, right now, this sXXX means XXX*XXX, but Google has no commitment to maintain this parameter schema. If you use this approach, need to watch out for changes (even though the possibility is low)

Comment: @IsabellaChen Yes, I got that. Thanks for clarifying. What's the best way to reach out to people about this? This is a bug in my opinion if I can't get the image of the size I want.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, but it's a valid feature request. I'm not sure what's the best channel for you, but I can try reach out to ask.

Comment: @IsabellaChen Thank you! Anyway I could track it somehow?

Comment: droidster you should select @IsabellaChen 's  answer as the correct answer. As she said, your answer's method has been deprecated and as such is invalid

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski Done. Thanks for reminding me. :)

Comment: Nowadays `loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer()` return `null`

Answer (score 2):

Hello I have found an alternative way for the latest Google Plus login, use **the method below:**

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private void latestGooglePlus() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestProfile().requestEmail().requestScopes(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN, Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE, new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"))
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .build();

    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, YOURREQUESTCODE);
}
```

And on **Activity result** use the code below:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("Activity Res", "" + requestCode);
    if (requestCode == YOURREQUESTCODE) {

        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
             GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            acct.getPhotoUrl();
            acct.getId();
            Log.e(TAG, acct.getDisplayName());
            Log.e(TAG, acct.getEmail());

            Plus.PeopleApi.load(mGoogleApiClient, acct.getId()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                    Person person = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().get(0);

                    Log.d(TAG, (person.getName().getGivenName()));
                    Log.d(TAG, (person.getName().getFamilyName()));

                    Log.d(TAG, (person.getDisplayName()));
                    Log.d(TAG, (person.getGender() + ""));
                    Log.d(TAG, "person.getCover():" + person.getCover().getCoverPhoto().getUrl());
                }
            });
        }
    }  
}
```

**Finally your onClick will be:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.txtGooglePlus:
            latestGooglePlus();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is follow the google orientation at [Add Google Sign-In to Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/).

Then you have to change the GoogleSignInOptions to:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

If you need to add another scopes you can do it like this:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

And at 'onActivityResult' inside 'if (result.isSuccess()) {' insert this:

```
new requestUserInfoAsync(this /* Context */, acct).execute();
```

and create this method:

```
private static class requestUserInfoAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // Global instance of the HTTP transport.
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    // Global instance of the JSON factory.
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    private Context context;
    private GoogleSignInAccount acct;

    private String birthdayText;
    private String addressText;
    private String cover;

    public requestUserInfoAsync(Context context, GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        this.context = context;
        this.acct = acct;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // On worker thread
        GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                context, Collections.singleton(Scopes.PROFILE)
        );
        credential.setSelectedAccount(new Account(acct.getEmail(), "com.google"));
        People service = new People.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(context.getString(R.string.app_name) /* whatever you like */)
                .build();

        // All the person details
        try {
            Person meProfile = service.people().get("people/me").execute();

            List<Birthday> birthdays = meProfile.getBirthdays();
            if (birthdays != null && birthdays.size() > 0) {
                Birthday birthday = birthdays.get(0);

                // DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(birthdayDate)
                birthdayText = "";
                try {
                    if (birthday.getDate().getYear() != null) {
                        birthdayText += birthday.getDate().getYear() + " ";
                    }
                    birthdayText += birthday.getDate().getMonth() + " " + birthday.getDate().getDay();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            List<Address> addresses = meProfile.getAddresses();
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                addressText = address.getFormattedValue();
            }

            List<CoverPhoto> coverPhotos = meProfile.getCoverPhotos();
            if (coverPhotos != null && coverPhotos.size() > 0) {
                CoverPhoto coverPhoto = coverPhotos.get(0);
                cover = coverPhoto.getUrl();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        Log.i("TagTag", "birthday: " + birthdayText);
        Log.i("TagTag", "address: " + addressText);
        Log.i("TagTag", "cover: " + cover);
    }
}
```

Using this you can use the methods inside 'Person meProfile' to get other info, but **you can only the get the public info of the user** otherwise it will be null.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Hardy's answer above, which guided me in the right direction.

I ended up using two calls to GoogleApiClient as I couldn't get what Hardy has above to work.

My first call is to the GoogleSignInApi

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(MY_GOOGLE_SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, ThinQStepsConstants.REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
```

This then give me the first part through the onActivityResult, the same as Hardy. However then I use the call to the GoogleApiClient.Builder again

```
mGoogleApiClientPlus = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .build();

mGoogleApiClientPlus.connect();
```

Now I can access the Plus.PeopleApi via the onConnected callback

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");

    Plus.PeopleApi.load(mGoogleApiClientPlus, mGoogleId).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
            Person currentPerson = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().get(0);
        }
    });

}
```

With appropriate disconnects and revokes.

You may notice my code uses the same callbacks, which I need to tidy up, but the principal is there.